# how to update other page title while active on other page?

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia, page-title

Say, I'm in "Create Order" page, once I placed an order and saved it, "Jobs [0]" page will increment by 1 and display as "Jobs [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRPff.png)". Something like that.

I already saw some answers here at SO but it utilizes the activate method in which the user have to be in the page before it'll change the page title. Please advise

Below is my sidebar

[image: sidebar]

Comment: try Window.postMessage() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume your sidebar menu was implemented like this.

```
<a 
  repeat.for="row of router.navigation"
  href.bind="row.href"
  class.bind="row.isActive ? 'active' : ''"
>${row.title}</a>
```

You don't need to update the route's title itself.

You are tracking the total job count in your front-end code anyway, just show that variable after title of route "jobs".

```
<a 
  repeat.for="row of router.navigation"
  href.bind="row.href"
  class.bind="row.isActive ? 'active' : ''"
>${row.title} <span if.bind="row.config.name == 'jobs'">[${jobCount}]</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply using `message_receive` event listener of `storage`, The function `message_receive` will be called every time you set any value of localStorage in any other tab.

Register event listener where you will get the message from diffrunt tab

```
window.addEventListener("storage", message_receive);

function message_receive(ev) {
    if (ev.key == 'message') {
        var message=ev.newValue;
        // Set your title here, using document.title='your formatted title'
    }
}
```

Message boradcast to broadcast the message to each listner

```
function message_broadcast(message) {
    localStorage.removeItem('message');
    localStorage.setItem('message',message);
}
```

Comment: like a pubsub, right? my problem now is how to target the page title I want to change

Comment: you can update page titile using `document.title='your formatted title'`

Comment: not sure how i can specifically target a page title on aurelia

Comment: You need to add extra javascript to identity the page you are currently in, you can check by url, or register event listner only you need to,

Comment: @BoyPasmo what issue are you facing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165019/discussion-between-boy-pasmo-and-programtreasures).